# Why does this case expression for foldr does not work?

Tags: haskell, case

The following function should take "7-8-X" and convert to [7,8,10]

```
convertCharToInteger :: Char -> Integer
convertCharToInteger = (read::String->Integer) . (:[])

parseAsNumbers :: String -> [Integer]
parseAsNumbers xs = foldr (\x acc -> case x of '-' -> acc
                                           'X' -> 10:acc
                                            _  -> (convertCharToInteger x):acc
                      ) [] xs
```

it gives me following error

Pattern syntax in expression context:

```
\x acc
    -> case x of {
      '-' -> acc
      'X' -> 10 : acc (...) } -> (convertCharToInteger x) : acc
```

Comment: you *indentation* is ragged. `_` is under `X`, not under the first `'` as it should be. Either be extra careful, or use explicit braces and semicolons, to be sure about the grouping of expressions.

Comment: Having added a type annotation for `convertCharToInteger`, you don' need to do likewise for `read`; the compiler knows that `read` has to return an `Integer`. Point-free style hurts here as well; `convertCharToInteger c = read [c]` is much simpler. (Although if you really want to be point-free, take advantage of the `Applicative` instance for lists: `convertCharToInteger = read . pure`).

Answer (score 0):

You should start listing the cases on a new line and align them like so:

```
parseAsNumbers :: String -> [Integer]
parseAsNumbers xs = foldr (\x acc -> case x of
                                       '-' -> acc
                                       'X' -> 10:acc
                                       _   -> (convertCharToInteger x):acc
                      ) [] xs
```

Comment: The new line is not necessary (though usually sensible), the important thing is that the cases are aligned.

Answer (score 0):

The patterns should be aligned, like this:

```
parseAsNumbers :: String -> [Integer]
parseAsNumbers xs = foldr (\x acc -> case x of '-' -> acc
                                               'X' -> 10:acc
                                               _   -> (convertCharToInteger x):acc) [] xs
```

Also, you could use `read` instead of `convertCharToInteger`.

```
parseAsNumbers :: String -> [Integer]
parseAsNumbers xs = foldr doit [] xs
    where
        doit = \x acc -> case x of
            '-' -> acc
            'X' -> (10:acc)
            _   -> (read [x]:acc)
```